# Sub-arrays of objects (based on the first 2 values) missing the 3+n values

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects (dictionary in Python terms) where the possible values for the ***FirstValue*** are `_1111_` or `_2222_` and for the ***SecondValue*** are `_first_` or `_second_` or `_third_`. So, in a matrix of scenarios we have 6 cases.

Now, I am trying to create sub-arrays for each case without missing any data for other objects. In the output below, if I focus on the first scenario (`_1111_` and `_first_`), I am missing the data when the ***ThirdValue*** is `VVV`.

Is there a way to substitute the reduce function below or do I have to start with a completely different mindset? (In this case I will not have aggregate the numbers).

```js
var json_data = {"headers":["FirstValue","SecondValue","ThirdValue","FourthValue","FifthValue","NumberOne","NumberTwo"],"rows":[["_2222_","_first_","CPV","unknown","_2222_",92310.8671,5226.386074028007],["_2222_","_first_","WWW","known","_2222_",92310.8671,5226.386074028007],["_2222_","_second_","VVV","unknown","_2222_",92310.8671,null],["_2222_","_third_","VVV","unknown","_2222_",92310.8671,5226.386074028007],["_1111_","_first_","VVV","unknown","random",197977.2658,36169.2693355163],["_1111_","_first_","WWW","unknown","random",197977.2658,36169.2693355163],["_1111_","_second_","VVV","unknown","random",197977.2658,36169.2693355163],["_1111_","_third_","WWW","display","random",26536.9836,1957.2823939366558]]};
 
var dataRows = json_data.rows;
var dataHeaders = json_data.headers;
var json =[];

//Convert JSON to dictionary
for (i = 0; i < dataRows.length; i++) 
{
  var object = {};
  for (j = 0; j < dataHeaders.length; j++) 
  {  
    object[dataHeaders[j]] = dataRows[i][j];
  }
  json.push(object);
}

var res = json.reduce((r, e) => {
  let {SecondValue, FirstValue} = e;
  r[FirstValue] = r[FirstValue] || {}
  r[FirstValue][SecondValue] = r[FirstValue][SecondValue] || {}
  r[FirstValue][SecondValue] = r[FirstValue][SecondValue] || {}
  Object.assign(r[FirstValue][SecondValue], e);
  return r;
}, {})

var array = Object.values(res).map(Object.values)

//Print the _1111_ branch
if("_1111_" in res){
 var _1111_ = res._1111_;
}

    //Print the _1111_ branch
    if("_first_" in _1111_){
      var _first_ = _1111_._first_;
      document.getElementById("one").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(_first_, null, 2);
    }
/*   
     if("_second_" in _1111_){
      var _second_ = _1111_._second_;
      document.getElementById("two").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(_second_, null, 2);
    }   

    if("_third_" in _1111_){
      var _third_ = _1111_._third_;
      document.getElementById("three").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(_third_, null, 2);
    }
*/
/*
//Print the _2222_ branch
if("_2222_" in res){
 var _2222_ = res._2222_;
} 

    //Print the _2222_ branch
    if("_first_" in _2222_){
      var _first_ = _2222_._first_;
      document.getElementById("four").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(_first_, null, 2);
    }

    if("_second_" in _2222_){
      var _second_ = _2222_._second_;
      document.getElementById("five").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(_second_, null, 2);
    }

    if("_third_" in _2222_){
      var _third_ = _2222_._third_;
      document.getElementById("six").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(_third_, null, 2);
    }
*/
```

```html
<h3>_1111_ - _first_</h3>
<div style="background:grey;" id="one"></div>
<!--
<h3>_1111_ - _second_</h3>
<div style="background:green;" id="two"></div>
<h3>_1111_ - _third_</h3>
<div style="background:grey;" id="three"></div>
<h3>_2222_ - _first_</h3>
<div style="background:green;" id="four"></div>
<h3>_2222_ - _second_</h3>
<div style="background:grey;" id="five"></div>
<h3>_2222_ - _third_</h3>
<div style="background:green;" id="six"></div>
-->
```

PS: I have kept the uncommented code as this is not a final version. Repetition of code might be replaced.

Comment: Please add the expected result.

Comment: What do you mean with _I am trying to create sub-arrays for each case_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you intend to get the output in this structure:

```js
const json_data =
{
  "headers":
    [
      "FirstValue",
      "SecondValue",
      "ThirdValue",
      "FourthValue",
      "FifthValue",
      "NumberOne",
      "NumberTwo"
    ],

  "rows":
    [
      [
        "_2222_",
        "_first_",
        "CPV",
        "unknown",
        "_2222_",
        92310.8671,
        5226.386074028007
      ],
      [
        "_2222_",
        "_first_",
        "WWW",
        "known",
        "_2222_",
        92310.8671,
        5226.386074028007
      ],
      [
        "_2222_",
        "_second_",
        "VVV",
        "unknown",
        "_2222_",
        92310.8671,
        null
      ],
      [
        "_2222_",
        "_third_",
        "VVV",
        "unknown",
        "_2222_",
        92310.8671,
        5226.386074028007
      ],
      [
        "_1111_",
        "_first_",
        "VVV",
        "unknown",
        "random",
        197977.2658,
        36169.2693355163
      ],
      [
        "_1111_",
        "_first_",
        "WWW",
        "unknown",
        "random",
        197977.2658,
        36169.2693355163
      ],
      [
        "_1111_",
        "_second_",
        "VVV",
        "unknown",
        "random",
        197977.2658,
        36169.2693355163
      ],
      [
        "_1111_",
        "_third_",
        "WWW",
        "display",
        "random",
        26536.9836,
        1957.2823939366558
      ]
    ]
};


// convert into array of objects [{FirstValue: 'abc', SecondValue: 'abc', ...}, ...]
let converted  = json_data.rows.map(e => e.reduce( (accumulated, val, idx) => ({...accumulated, [json_data.headers[idx]]: val}), {} ) );
// console.log('CONVERTED\n', converted);


// to get an ordered and filtered output, let's do some stuff...

const ordinal  = ['_first_', '_second_', '_third_'];

// get an ordered unique array of the first two fields of each row, e.g. [['_1111_', '_first_'], ...]
//   using a Set of JSON-Strings converted back to an array.
let   unique01 = Array.from( new Set(json_data.rows.map((val, i) => JSON.stringify(val.slice(0,2)))) )
      .map(JSON.parse)
      // order by first field, then by second field
      .sort( (e1,e2) =>  e2[0] !== e1[0] ? e2[0] < e1[0] : ordinal.indexOf(e2[1]) < ordinal.indexOf(e1[1]) )
;
// console.log('UNIQUE\n', unique01);

let e = document.getElementById('data-container');

// output filtered data sets as JSON
for(let v of unique01)
  e.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',
    `    <h1>${v.join(' - ')}</h1>${converted.filter( e => e.FirstValue === v[0] && e.SecondValue === v[1] )
                                             .reduce( (aggregated,o)=>`${aggregated}
<div>${JSON.stringify(o)}</div>`
                                                      , '')
                                   }
` );
```

```html
<div id="data-container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With `Object.assign(r[FirstValue][SecondValue], e)` you overwrite any previous data for the `ThirdValue` property with the new one in `e`. If you need to keep both, then it is probably better to use an array per combination of FirstValue and SecondValue:

```
let {SecondValue, FirstValue} = e;
r[FirstValue] = r[FirstValue] || {};
r[FirstValue][SecondValue] = r[FirstValue][SecondValue] || [];  
//                                                         ^^
r[FirstValue][SecondValue].push(e);
//                         ^^^^^^^
return r;
```

You'll then need to adapt the rest of your processing to this modified data structure.